# Java boxing or unboxing

Tags: java, integer, boxing, unboxing

I found an example where I cannot find the number of boxing and unboxing in the Java code below :

```
Integer x = 5;
int y = x + x;
```

I would say that there is one type of unboxing (`int y = x + x`), but I am not sure about that. Is there any boxing as well?

Comment: `x` is unboxed twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one boxing in `Integer x = 5`. The `int` 5 is boxed to `Integer`.

There are two un-boxings in `int y = x + x`: `Integer x` is unboxed twice.

Answer (score 1):

There is only boxing

```
Integer x = 5
```

From Docs:

> If p is a value of type int, then boxing conversion converts p into a
>   reference r of class and type Integer, such that r.intValue() == p

Why? Because we are reference only once
And there are two unboxing in :

```
int y = x + x
```

From Docs

> If r is a reference of type Integer, then unboxing conversion converts
>   r into r.intValue()

Why? Because we are calling two times `x.IntValue()`

Following this docs from [Boxing and Unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7)

Answer (score 0):

Change values from Primitive value to Wrapper Class Values in java  example

```
Integer a = 10;
int b = a;
```

https://youtu.be/96pq0mpFz9M

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for your contribution! It would be nice if you would read this guide [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and adjust your answer accordingly. In detail you should write the essential explanation as text here and not linking it as video. When you're so kind to do it you can also remove the video-link. Thanks!